# How do I manipulate data that is located in state and display to page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making three separate axios calls that each set the state with some data. Where do I do my data manipulation with the state data not to change the state but to display something else where?

For example out of the transactionItems state, I want to get all transactions for the current date. All transaction items have the date set automatically when its added to the database.

I'm having issues parsing the data because my setstate seems to update 3 times with all the axios calls.

There are other data manipulations I would like to be able to do as well but I feel like I'll hit another roadblock.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import moment from "moment";
import TransactionSummary from "./TransactionSummary";
import BudgetSummary from "./BudgetSummary";
import DebtSummary from "./DebtSummary";

class DashboardTable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      transactionItems: [],
      budgetItems: [],
      debtItems: [],
      spentToday: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getTransactionData();
    this.getBudgetData();
    this.getDebtData();
  }

  getTransactionData = () => {
    axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = localStorage.getItem(
      "jwtToken"
    );
    axios
      .get("/api/transactions")
      .then(res =>
        this.setState({
          transactionItems: res.data
        })
      )
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  getBudgetData = () => {
    axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = localStorage.getItem(
      "jwtToken"
    );
    axios
      .get("/api/budgets")
      .then(res =>
        this.setState({
          budgetItems: res.data
        })
      )
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  getDebtData = () => {
    axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = localStorage.getItem(
      "jwtToken"
    );
    axios
      .get("/api/debts")
      .then(res =>
        this.setState({
          debtItems: res.data
        })
      )
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="content">
          <TransactionSummary transactionItems={this.state.transactionItems} />

          <BudgetSummary budgetItems={this.state.budgetItems} />

          <DebtSummary debtItems={this.state.debtItems} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DashboardTable;
```

Here's DebtSummary component

```
import React from "react";

const DebtSummary = props => {
  let sumOfDebtItems = props.debtItems.reduce((a, c) => {
    return a + c["balance"];
  }, 0);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Debt Summary</p>

      {sumOfDebtItems}
    </div>
  );
};

export default DebtSummary;
```

Comment: Manipulate the data in their respective components by assigning to a that relevant component state. It would be great if you can share TransactionSummary, BudgetSummary and DebtSummary components code as well

Comment: Added above - there's not much in them yet

Comment: If there are no dependencies then I would like to make a break in state and call axis inside these three components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Hemadri said, the easiest way to do this is to move the 3 axios calls into their respective component

You can also move the data manipulation into a separate method and call it in the render method. You can write as many of these as you need, they can all read from the same state variable

**DebtSummary example:**

```
import React from "react";

class DebtSummary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      debtItems: []
    }
  }

  getDebtData = () => {
    axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = localStorage.getItem(
      "jwtToken"
    );
    axios
      .get("/api/debts")
      .then(res =>
       this.setState({
         debtItems: res.data
        })
      )
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  // Do some data manipulation, in the case computing the debt sum
  sumOfDebtItems = () => {
    return this.state.debtItems.reduce((a, c) => {
        return a + c["balance"];
    }, 0);
  }

  // Load the debt data once the component has mounted
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getDebtData()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <p>Debt Summary</p>
       {this.sumOfDebtItems()}
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default DebtSummary;
```